# How to create new database on heroku server with postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I want to create a PostgreSQL database on a Heroku server.

My `database.yml` is

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql

  encoding: utf8

  database: ddb
  username: postgres

  port: 5432
  password: admin

  host: localhost
```

When I run `heroku rake db:create` it gives me the error:

```
mydatabase already exists
    (in /disk1/home/slugs/181380_8d7032f_f439-4fe4f5a6-f181-4150-a968-fadcf45f0af5/mnt)
```

I have tried it for various different database names, but get the same message.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: A wild guess: the config file you cited is not the config file Heroku sees. Look for a similar file with a "database: mydatabase" in it.

Answer (score 15):

***heroku autogenerates database.yml*** on the deploy. Reads like: it doesn't matter what you put in your database.yml, which to me is nice, as I can include it in git without worrying about production db passwords.

You may choose another database by setting the ENV['DATABASE_URL']  (use `heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=....`)

Check heroku documentation
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#build-behavior

Comment: Heroku does not autogenerate `database.yml` after `Rails 4.1` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior